# jenkins kubernetes plugin running the pods in loop and job is never build

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

i am using jenkins kubernetes plugin.Configure it and testing a sample pipeline code as below:

```
podTemplate(containers: [
        containerTemplate(name: 'ssh-client', image: 'kroniak/ssh-client:3.6', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat')
]) {
    node(POD_LABEL) {
        stage('container log') {
            container('ssh-client') {
                sshagent (credentials: ['ContainerExecDecoratorPipelineTest-sshagent']) {
                    sh 'env'
                    sh 'ssh-add -L'
                    sh 'ssh -vT -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" git@github.com'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

while this is building i can check my kubernetes cluster and noticed that pods are creating but terminating also after few seconds. It keeps happening infinitely. I even checked with all other sample pipelines. The console output in Jenkins shows :

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] podTemplate
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] node
Created Pod: ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-j19bl
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-j19bl][Scheduled] Successfully assigned ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-j19bl to docker-desktop
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-j19bl][Pulling] Pulling image "kroniak/ssh-client:3.6"
Still waiting to schedule task
‘tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-j19bl’ is offline
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-j19bl][Pulled] Successfully pulled image "kroniak/ssh-client:3.6"
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-j19bl][Created] Created container ssh-client
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-j19bl][Started] Started container ssh-client
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-j19bl][Pulled] Container image "jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4" already present on machine
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-j19bl][Created] Created container jnlp
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-j19bl][Started] Started container jnlp
Created Pod: ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-23hwk
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-23hwk][Scheduled] Successfully assigned ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-23hwk to docker-desktop
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-23hwk][Pulled] Container image "kroniak/ssh-client:3.6" already present on machine
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-23hwk][Created] Created container ssh-client
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-23hwk][Started] Started container ssh-client
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-23hwk][Pulled] Container image "jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4" already present on machine
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-23hwk][Created] Created container jnlp
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-23hwk][Started] Started container jnlp
Created Pod: ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-wnxr9
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-wnxr9][Scheduled] Successfully assigned ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-wnxr9 to docker-desktop
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-wnxr9][Pulled] Container image "kroniak/ssh-client:3.6" already present on machine
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-wnxr9][Created] Created container ssh-client
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-wnxr9][Started] Started container ssh-client
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-wnxr9][Pulled] Container image "jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4" already present on machine
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-wnxr9][Created] Created container jnlp
[Normal][ns-jenkins/tests-14-zm889-hxd6p-wnxr9][Started] Started container jnlp
```

Comment: Can you do `kubectl logs PODNAME` on one of your pods and see if anything is being output?

Comment: @BrianPursley It happens to me too, I don't know how to get logs because they are inexistent like if they are removed after created.

Comment: Try `kubectl logs -p PODNAME` or use `kubectl describe`

Comment: Also post this is a new question if you want help, it is hard to answer in comments and other people won’t be able to find the answer easily.

Answer (score 2):

`kubectl logs <jenkins-pod> --namespace=<jenkins-namespace>` is a good starting point to start debugging the issue.

When you define your Kubernetes clusters under `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Cloud -> Kubernetes Cloud Details`, does the Jenkins URL match the Endpoint address in `kubectl describe service jenkins`?

The Endpoint address must match the Jenkins URL in the Kubernetes Cloud Details

```
kubectl describe service jenkins -n jenkins | grep Endpoint
Endpoints: 192.168.151.57:8080
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I ran the command `kubectl logs -l jenkins=slave -f` then I was able to identify the issue.

The issue was `Failed to connect to jenkins-agent:50000` so I think the agent pod wasn't able to connect to jenkins-agent on port 50000.

I went to `https://your-jenkins-domain.com/configureSecurity/` and set TCP port for inbound agents to 50000.

The issue is gone after I made that change